# Optimizing a query that uses a lot of aggregates

Tags: sql, sql-server

Heys guys, I asked yesterday about optimizing a query, and with some help I managed to get my query from taking 20 seconds to running instantly.

This was the question (and it contains an example of the underlying table) -> [Is there any way to improve the efficiency of this SQL query and make it run faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58015322/is-there-any-way-to-improve-the-efficiency-of-this-sql-query-and-make-it-run-fas)

The problem was solved by being smarter about aggregates and group by. However, I still have some trouble with group by. I want to post another query that is against the exact same table and see if anyone sees anyway to improve the efficiency of this query.

So originally, this query was a whole mess. I tried to apply a similar GROUP BY technique that fixed the first query to this query as well but it didn't really pan out.

Here is what I ended up with after I cleaned everything up:

```
BEGIN

DECLARE @LocalCompanyCode VARCHAR(5)
SET @LocalCompanyCode = '09'

DECLARE @LocalDivisionCode VARCHAR(5)
SET @LocalDivisionCode = '001'

DECLARE @LocalCustomerBaseFromDate DATETIME 
SET @LocalCustomerBaseFromDate = '1/1/2018' 

DECLARE @LocalCustomerBaseToDate DATETIME
SET @LocalCustomerBaseToDate = '9/1/2019' 

DECLARE @LocalRecurringBaseFromDate DATETIME
SET @LocalRecurringBaseFromDate = '1/1/2017'

DECLARE @LocalLifetimeBaseFromDate DATETIME 
SET @LocalLifetimeBaseFromDate = '1/1/2016' 

    SELECT 
    *
    FROM (

        SELECT 

        Email
        ,Date_Created
        ,BrandNewCustomer
        ,RecurringCustomer
        ,ReactivatedCustomer
        ,TotalOrders
        ,TotalCustomerValue
        ,TotalQuantity
        ,TotalOrdersNewBase
        ,TotalCustomerValueNewBase
        ,TotalQuantityNewBase
        ,TotalOrdersRecurringBase
        ,TotalCustomerValueRecurringBase
        ,TotalQuantityRecurringBase
        ,TotalOrdersLifetimeBase
        ,TotalCustomerValueLifetimeBase
        ,TotalQuantityLifetimeBase

        ,SUM(TotalCustomerValueNewBase)  Over () BaseCustomersTotal
        ,SUM(TotalCustomerValueRecurringBase) Over ()  RecurringCustomersTotal
        ,SUM(TotalCustomerValueLifetimeBase) Over () LifetimeCustomersTotal
        ,SUM(TotalCustomerValue) Over ()  AllCustomersTotal

        ,(dense_rank() over (order by (case when Date_Created BETWEEN @LocalCustomerBaseFromDate and DATEADD(dayofyear, 1, @LocalCustomerBaseToDate) then Email end) asc) +
         dense_rank() over (order by  (case when Date_Created BETWEEN @LocalCustomerBaseFromDate and DATEADD(dayofyear, 1, @LocalCustomerBaseToDate) then Email end) desc) - 1
        ) as TotalCustomersOverCustomerBase

        ,(dense_rank() over (order by (case when Date_Created BETWEEN @LocalRecurringBaseFromDate and @LocalCustomerBaseFromDate then Email end) asc) +
         dense_rank() over (order by  (case when Date_Created BETWEEN @LocalRecurringBaseFromDate and @LocalCustomerBaseFromDate then Email end) desc) - 1
        ) as TotalCustomersOverRecurringBase

        ,(dense_rank() over (order by (case when Date_Created BETWEEN @LocalLifetimeBaseFromDate and @LocalRecurringBaseFromDate then Email end) asc) +
         dense_rank() over (order by  (case when Date_Created BETWEEN @LocalLifetimeBaseFromDate and @LocalRecurringBaseFromDate then Email end) desc) - 1
        ) as TotalCustomersOverLifetimeBase

        ,(DENSE_RANK() over (order by Email asc) 
        +DENSE_RANK() over ( order by Email desc) 
        - 1) as TotalCustomersOverBase

    ,SUM( CASE WHEN (BrandNewCustomer + RecurringCustomer + ReactivatedCustomer) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) over () KeptCustomers
    ,SUM( CASE WHEN (BrandNewCustomer + RecurringCustomer + ReactivatedCustomer) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) over () LostCustomers

        FROM (
            SELECT 

            T.Email

            ,MAX(T.Date_Created) Date_Created

            ,COUNT(*) TotalOrders
            ,SUM(T.Order_Sell_price) TotalCustomerValue
            ,SUM(T.Quantity_Ordered) TotalQuantity

            ,SUM(CASE WHEN T.Date_Created BETWEEN @LocalCustomerBaseFromDate and DATEADD(dayofyear, 1, @LocalCustomerBaseToDate) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  TotalOrdersNewBase
            ,SUM(CASE WHEN T.Date_Created BETWEEN @LocalCustomerBaseFromDate and DATEADD(dayofyear, 1, @LocalCustomerBaseToDate) THEN Order_Sell_price ELSE 0 END)   TotalCustomerValueNewBase
            ,SUM(CASE WHEN T.Date_Created BETWEEN @LocalCustomerBaseFromDate and DATEADD(dayofyear, 1, @LocalCustomerBaseToDate) THEN Quantity_Ordered ELSE 0 END)   TotalQuantityNewBase

            ,SUM(CASE WHEN T.Date_Created BETWEEN @LocalRecurringBaseFromDate and @LocalCustomerBaseFromDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  TotalOrdersRecurringBase
            ,SUM(CASE WHEN T.Date_Created BETWEEN @LocalRecurringBaseFromDate and @LocalCustomerBaseFromDate THEN Order_Sell_price ELSE 0 END)   TotalCustomerValueRecurringBase
            ,SUM(CASE WHEN T.Date_Created BETWEEN @LocalRecurringBaseFromDate and @LocalCustomerBaseFromDate THEN Quantity_Ordered ELSE 0 END)   TotalQuantityRecurringBase

            ,SUM(CASE WHEN T.Date_Created BETWEEN @LocalLifetimeBaseFromDate and @LocalRecurringBaseFromDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  TotalOrdersLifetimeBase
            ,SUM(CASE WHEN T.Date_Created BETWEEN @LocalLifetimeBaseFromDate and @LocalRecurringBaseFromDate THEN Order_Sell_price ELSE 0 END)   TotalCustomerValueLifetimeBase
            ,SUM(CASE WHEN T.Date_Created BETWEEN @LocalLifetimeBaseFromDate and @LocalRecurringBaseFromDate THEN Quantity_Ordered ELSE 0 END)   TotalQuantityLifetimeBase

            ,CASE WHEN  
                (   ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN T.Date_Created BETWEEN @LocalCustomerBaseFromDate and DATEADD(dayofyear, 1, @LocalCustomerBaseToDate) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0) >= 1
                AND ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN T.Date_Created BETWEEN @LocalRecurringBaseFromDate and @LocalCustomerBaseFromDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0) = 0
                AND ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN T.Date_Created BETWEEN @LocalLifetimeBaseFromDate and @LocalRecurringBaseFromDate THEN Quantity_Ordered ELSE 0 END),0) = 0) 
            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END BrandNewCustomer

            ,CASE WHEN  
                (   ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN T.Date_Created BETWEEN @LocalCustomerBaseFromDate and DATEADD(dayofyear, 1, @LocalCustomerBaseToDate) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0)  >= 1 
                AND ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN T.Date_Created BETWEEN @LocalRecurringBaseFromDate and @LocalCustomerBaseFromDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0) >= 1)
            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END RecurringCustomer

            ,CASE WHEN  
                (   ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN T.Date_Created BETWEEN @LocalCustomerBaseFromDate and DATEADD(dayofyear, 1, @LocalCustomerBaseToDate) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0) >= 1 
                AND ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN T.Date_Created BETWEEN @LocalRecurringBaseFromDate and @LocalCustomerBaseFromDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0) = 0
                AND ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN T.Date_Created BETWEEN @LocalLifetimeBaseFromDate and @LocalRecurringBaseFromDate THEN Quantity_Ordered ELSE 0 END),0) >= 1) 
            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ReactivatedCustomer

            FROM (
                SELECT 

                F.Email
                ,F.Coal_Date Date_Created
                ,Month(F.Coal_Date) Month
                ,Year(F.Coal_Date) Year
                ,F.Customer_Purchase_Order_Number
                ,F.Order_Status
                ,Row_Number() over (Partition by Email order by Coal_Date asc) OrderCount
                ,F.Order_Sell_price
                ,F.Order_Quantity_Ordered Quantity_Ordered

                FROM
                    FinalEcomTable F

                WHERE
                    1=1
                    AND (F.Company_Code = @LocalCompanyCode OR @LocalCompanyCode IS NULL)  
                    AND (F.Division_Code = @LocalDivisionCode OR @LocalDivisionCode IS NULL)
                    AND F.Coal_Date BETWEEN @LocalLifetimeBaseFromDate AND DATEADD(dayofyear, 1, @LocalCustomerBaseToDate)
                    AND F.Order_Status <> 'CANCELLED'
                    AND F.Odet_Line_Number = 1
            ) T

            GROUP BY T.Email

        ) TT

    ) TTT

    WHERE (BrandNewCustomer + RecurringCustomer + ReactivatedCustomer) = 1
    ORDER BY email DESC

END
```

And here is the full execution plan:

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SkDyXPfDH

Those 4 dense_rank lines by themselves are almost doubling the run time. I realize now that its usually always these types of lines that do that.

I'll try to explain a bit about my thinking behind the query. So it is based on the same table as my first query. In reality, I am dealing with lots of data across three different linked servers, so I decided to create one master table that I would update every day and instead of calling to the linked servers and causing everything to run super slow, I would just call to that table.

So the most inner query takes each customer email, and then by each email, gets each order and what order number this is (first, second, etc). Is it a problem that I am doing Over () for my Row_Number aggregate? I would want to Group By Email but then how would I get each actual order number? Because if I group be email, then I have to do something like Max() of each order number, but I want the actual order number. Is there any way to do this?

Then the next outer query takes this data and actually groups by email. Over this group by I calculate totals over certain date ranges. The idea for this report is that there are three date ranges. New, which is what the actual report is based on and that range is something like the past 3 months. I look at all the customers in the past three months and then I see if they have any purchases in the recurring date range (a year before the three months) or the lifetime date range. Then I determine whether they are new customer or a recurring customer (or reactivated) by just putting a 1 on which type of customer it is.

Then my final outer query takes that data and calculates overall totals like Total value of all my recurring customers or total kept vs lost customers and so on. And like I mentioned before the dense_ranks really trip me up here. I feel like if I could add a Group By to this last query, I can solve a lot of my performance problems, but I can't seem to figure out how to integrate it.

Currently, this query runs about 10-15 seconds and I feel it could be instant. I tried creating the index the execution plan suggested but it didn't do anything.

Comment: Have you try to follow the suggest from your query plan ? `CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ON [dbo].[FinalEcomTable] ([Odet_Line_Number],[Coal_Date],[Order_Status]) INCLUDE ([Company_Code],[Division_Code],[Order_Quantity_Ordered],[Order_Sell_price],[Email])`

Comment: I did. It didn't help. However, I did replace my dense_ranks with Count and than cut my query time in half from 15 to 7

Comment: Hi @nathan, Is there any clustered index exists for the table `FinalEcomTable`, if not, was there any advantage or restriction to maintain the table as HEAP (without any clustered index)